# Implement tree-shaking in typescript

Tags: typescript, tree-shaking

I'm building a re-usable telemetry library using TypeScript and OpenTelemetry. I'm trying to see how I can implement tree-shaking such that consumer can import only the modules they need and not everything and so they can reduce the overall bundle size. The project structure looks like this,

```
lib
|
|__ trace
|    |____ TraceClass.ts
|    |____ index.ts
|
|__ metrics
|    |____ MetricClass.ts
|    |____ index.ts
|
|__ logs
|    |____ LogClass.ts
|    |____ index.ts
|
|__ index.ts
```

I've three major modules "trace", "log" and "metrics" as separate folders. As you see each of the module has it's own "index.ts" file and there is a root "index.ts" file. Let's say if the root "index.ts" file exports all the things like of the sub-modules.

**root index.ts**

```
export * from './trace';
export * from './metrics';
export * from './logs';
```

Let's say the consumer import the `TraceClass` from the root file as below,

```
import { TraceClass } from 'mytelemetrylib';
```

Does the above code imports all the modules in their code?

or they have to do something like this?

```
import { TraceClass } from 'mytelemetrylib/trace';
```

Comment: It is always the consumer's responsibility to provide tree shaking. It depends on their build process. There's no way for the library developer to know which modules will be requested.

Answer (score 0):

If in the `index.ts` of the trace folder:

```
lib
|
|__ trace
|    |____ TraceClass.ts
|    |____ index.ts
```

You've exported everything (e.g `export * from './TraceClass';`) and within the `TraceClass.ts` the class is also exported (e.g `export class TraceClass`) then `import` have access to all of the things explicitly exported (e.g `import { TraceClass } from 'mytelemetrylib';` will be enough).

Additionally, you could "namespace" the exports for code clarity. For example:

```
export * as Trace from './trace';
export * as Metrics from './metrics';
export * as Logs from './logs';
```

The consumer could then import:

```
import { Trace, Metrics, Logs } from 'mytelemetrylib';
```

And use them with:

```
Trace.TraceClass // or any other explicitly exported trace related functionality.
```